# try to implement twitter-like message reply in Flask MiniTwit example

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I trid to implement twitter-like message reply in Flask MiniTwit example, but now I can't make the 'reply' button for each message work, how?

```
<ul class=messages>
{% for message in messages %}
<li><img src="{{ g.get_user(message.author_id).email|gravatar(size=48)}}"><p>
<strong><a href="{{ url_for('user_timeline', username=message.author_id)
}}">{{ message.author_id }}</a></strong>
{{ message.text }}
<small>&mdash; {{ message.pub_date|datetimeformat }}</small>
{% if g.user %}
<script type=text/javascript>
 $(function () {
  messageid = $('a#reply').data('messageid');
  $('a#reply').bind('click', function () {
  $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_get_replies', {
    messageid: $('#reply').data('messageid'),
    userid: $('#reply').data('userid')
  }, function (data) {
 $('div#' + messageid).text(data.result)
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
<p  align=right style='text-align:right'><small>
<a href=# data-userid="{{g.user._id}}" data-messageid="{{message._id}}" id="reply">
Reply
</a></small></p>
<p><div id="{{message._id}}">I TRY TO PUT REPLIES HERE!</div></p>
{% endif %}
{% else %}
<li><em>There's no message so far.</em>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

before click 'reply' button, My page is like:

[image: before click 'reply' button]

After click any of the 'reply' buttons, the page is like:

[image: After click any of the 'reply' buttons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) when you are returning HTML - the HTML is escaped, resulting in your issue - use [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead:

```
// Change
$('div#' + messageid).text(data.result)
// to
$('div#' + messageid).html(data.result)
                      ^^^^
```

A couple of other points to consider:

1. Each ID should exist only once in the document.  Having multiple links with the ID "reply" will result in issues later on.  Leave it out entirely, or change it to a class.
2. Use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) ([`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if you are using jQuery 1.7 or greater) and bind *just once* to the root element (in your case `ul.messages`).  This reduces the number of event handlers on the page to 1 - and will result in greatly increased performance with a large number of messages.
3. Cache your selectors to improve performance even more - no need to go to the DOM 3 times when you have all of your information in the first pass.

Comment: i've achieved my point, thanks your greate advice! I'm not clear with "Cache your selectors ..."

Comment: @BrentJiang - Basically, instead of doing `$("some#selector").some_action()` and then on the next line doing `$("some#selector").another_action()` you want to do this: `var some_thing = $("some#selector"); some_thing.some_action(); some_thing.another_action();`  This way jQuery only has to search through the DOM once and you'll get a free performance boost.